# One boxing comments from advertised network questions doesn't work

Tags: bug, chat, advertising, onebox

So, say you've found a network advertised question:

> [image]

And you click it...

And then you find a comment you like and want to paste that in to chat (one boxed):

> [image: comment]

but when you do,

> [image: results of oneboxing]

it doesn't work.  So you try again editing it (and blaming caching):

> [image: try two]

But now you've got the [history](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/18602465/history) you can see easily:

> [image: history]

And so while [`https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3494/how-to-count-all-of-the-windows-in-a-frame?utm_medium=ad&utm_source=http-apple-stackexchange-com-questions-110068-imovie-10-mavericks-altering-the&utm_campaign=emacs.stackexchange.com-promo&utm_content=3494#comment4979_3494`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3494/how-to-count-all-of-the-windows-in-a-frame?utm_medium=ad&utm_source=http-apple-stackexchange-com-questions-110068-imovie-10-mavericks-altering-the&utm_campaign=emacs.stackexchange.com-promo&utm_content=3494#comment4979_3494) will take you to the comment, it does not onebox correctly.

The advertising campaign appears to be rather sticky to the links *and* confusing to the onbox.  Fixing either of those would likely fix the bug.

P.S. How did `http-apple-stackexchange-com` get in there when the origin site was Programmers.SE?

Comment: I'd say the real problem is that those ugly ad link URLs aren't automatically redirected to the clean canonical ones by the SE servers.